# No matching records found datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

Mi Datatable no pinta las filas; el JSON devuelve todas los datos incluso se muestra cuantos datos a obtenido pero no aprace mas.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#dtclientes').dataTable( {
          processing: false,
          serverSide: true,
          ajax: {
              url: "lsclients",
              type: "GET",
              dataSrc: ""
          },
          columns: [
            {data:"name" },
            {data:"type" },
            {data:"document" },
            {data:"phone" },
            {data:"status" },
            {data:"id" }
          ]
        });
  });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

A mi asi me pinta perfecto, creo que tu problema esta en la dataSrc:"" o bien en la composicion del json:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rank').DataTable( {
            'responsive': 'true',
            'ajax': {
                'method': 'POST',
                'url': 'table/basededatos.php',
            },
            "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
            'columns' :[
                {data: 'nombre'},
                {data: 'assists'},
                {data: 'bestRankPoint'},
                {data: 'boosts'},
                {data: 'dBNOs'},
                {data: 'dailyKills'},
                {data: 'dailyWins'},
                {data: 'damageDealt'},
                {data: 'days'},
                {data: 'headshotKills'},
                {data: 'heals'},
                {data: 'killPoints'},
                {data: 'kills'},
                {data: 'longestKill'},
                {data: 'longestTimeSurvived'},
                {data: 'losses'},
                {data: 'maxKillStreaks'},
                {data: 'mostSurvivalTime'},
                {data: 'rankPoints'},
                {data: 'rankPointsTitle'},
                {data: 'revives'},
                {data: 'rideDistance'},
                {data: 'roadKills'},
                {data: 'roundMostKills'},
                {data: 'roundsPlayed'},
                {data: 'suicides'},
                {data: 'swimDistance'},
                {data: 'teamKills'},
                {data: 'timeSurvived'},
                {data: 'top10s'},
                {data: 'vehicleDestroys'},
                {data: 'walkDistance'},
                {data: 'weaponsAcquired'},
                {data: 'weeklyKills'},
                {data: 'weeklyWins'},
                {data: 'winPoints'},
                {data: 'wins'},
            ]
        } );
    } );
```

y aqui el Json:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "idRank":"28",
         "nombre":"KeTeMeTo",
         "assists":"0",
         "bestRankPoint":"0",
         "boosts":"0",
         "dBNOs":"0",
         "dailyKills":"0",
         "dailyWins":"0",
         "damageDealt":"0",
         "days":"0",
         "headshotKills":"0",
         "heals":"0",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"0",
         "longestKill":"0",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"0",
         "losses":"0",
         "maxKillStreaks":"0",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"0",
         "rankPoints":"0",
         "rankPointsTitle":"0",
         "revives":"0",
         "rideDistance":"0",
         "roadKills":"0",
         "roundMostKills":"0",
         "roundsPlayed":"0",
         "suicides":"0",
         "swimDistance":"0",
         "teamKills":"0",
         "timeSurvived":"0",
         "top10s":"0",
         "vehicleDestroys":"0",
         "walkDistance":"0",
         "weaponsAcquired":"0",
         "weeklyKills":"0",
         "weeklyWins":"0",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"0",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      },
      {
         "idRank":"29",
         "nombre":"Nomemate",
         "assists":"34",
         "bestRankPoint":"3007.02",
         "boosts":"120",
         "dBNOs":"61",
         "dailyKills":"42",
         "dailyWins":"2",
         "damageDealt":"11053.896",
         "days":"4",
         "headshotKills":"19",
         "heals":"164",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"70",
         "longestKill":"444.045",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"1781.7",
         "losses":"64",
         "maxKillStreaks":"3",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"1781.7",
         "rankPoints":"3007.02",
         "rankPointsTitle":"4-5",
         "revives":"26",
         "rideDistance":"87993.7",
         "roadKills":"26",
         "roundMostKills":"4",
         "roundsPlayed":"67",
         "suicides":"1",
         "swimDistance":"819.933",
         "teamKills":"2",
         "timeSurvived":"48107.4",
         "top10s":"28",
         "vehicleDestroys":"1",
         "walkDistance":"77418.9",
         "weaponsAcquired":"333",
         "weeklyKills":"70",
         "weeklyWins":"5",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"5",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      },
      {
         "idRank":"30",
         "nombre":"Unnk",
         "assists":"2",
         "bestRankPoint":"2259.41",
         "boosts":"16",
         "dBNOs":"2",
         "dailyKills":"0",
         "dailyWins":"0",
         "damageDealt":"995.7092",
         "days":"5",
         "headshotKills":"1",
         "heals":"39",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"2",
         "longestKill":"40.5224",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"1572.88",
         "losses":"29",
         "maxKillStreaks":"1",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"1572.88",
         "rankPoints":"2259.41",
         "rankPointsTitle":"3-4",
         "revives":"2",
         "rideDistance":"17423.6",
         "roadKills":"2",
         "roundMostKills":"1",
         "roundsPlayed":"29",
         "suicides":"2",
         "swimDistance":"219.849",
         "teamKills":"2",
         "timeSurvived":"21634.1",
         "top10s":"9",
         "vehicleDestroys":"0",
         "walkDistance":"27833.8",
         "weaponsAcquired":"74",
         "weeklyKills":"2",
         "weeklyWins":"0",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"0",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      },
      {
         "idRank":"31",
         "nombre":"Shoring",
         "assists":"27",
         "bestRankPoint":"2823.06",
         "boosts":"118",
         "dBNOs":"51",
         "dailyKills":"7",
         "dailyWins":"0",
         "damageDealt":"9135.713",
         "days":"15",
         "headshotKills":"16",
         "heals":"200",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"62",
         "longestKill":"276.026",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"1989.3",
         "losses":"71",
         "maxKillStreaks":"3",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"1989.3",
         "rankPoints":"2823.06",
         "rankPointsTitle":"3-1",
         "revives":"19",
         "rideDistance":"108571",
         "roadKills":"19",
         "roundMostKills":"6",
         "roundsPlayed":"75",
         "suicides":"1",
         "swimDistance":"903.703",
         "teamKills":"2",
         "timeSurvived":"63843.7",
         "top10s":"30",
         "vehicleDestroys":"1",
         "walkDistance":"113126",
         "weaponsAcquired":"327",
         "weeklyKills":"7",
         "weeklyWins":"0",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"5",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      },
      {
         "idRank":"32",
         "nombre":"Triviani",
         "assists":"43",
         "bestRankPoint":"3064.49",
         "boosts":"170",
         "dBNOs":"99",
         "dailyKills":"21",
         "dailyWins":"1",
         "damageDealt":"15234.359",
         "days":"8",
         "headshotKills":"23",
         "heals":"253",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"103",
         "longestKill":"329.79",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"1769.72",
         "losses":"66",
         "maxKillStreaks":"2",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"1769.72",
         "rankPoints":"3064.49",
         "rankPointsTitle":"4-5",
         "revives":"21",
         "rideDistance":"97804.4",
         "roadKills":"21",
         "roundMostKills":"10",
         "roundsPlayed":"68",
         "suicides":"0",
         "swimDistance":"34.0391",
         "teamKills":"0",
         "timeSurvived":"59142.6",
         "top10s":"31",
         "vehicleDestroys":"1",
         "walkDistance":"87388.1",
         "weaponsAcquired":"314",
         "weeklyKills":"71",
         "weeklyWins":"2",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"4",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      },
      {
         "idRank":"33",
         "nombre":"Trunks",
         "assists":"0",
         "bestRankPoint":"0",
         "boosts":"0",
         "dBNOs":"0",
         "dailyKills":"0",
         "dailyWins":"0",
         "damageDealt":"0",
         "days":"0",
         "headshotKills":"0",
         "heals":"0",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"0",
         "longestKill":"0",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"0",
         "losses":"0",
         "maxKillStreaks":"0",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"0",
         "rankPoints":"0",
         "rankPointsTitle":"0",
         "revives":"0",
         "rideDistance":"0",
         "roadKills":"0",
         "roundMostKills":"0",
         "roundsPlayed":"0",
         "suicides":"0",
         "swimDistance":"0",
         "teamKills":"0",
         "timeSurvived":"0",
         "top10s":"0",
         "vehicleDestroys":"0",
         "walkDistance":"0",
         "weaponsAcquired":"0",
         "weeklyKills":"0",
         "weeklyWins":"0",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"0",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      },
      {
         "idRank":"34",
         "nombre":"Dudone",
         "assists":"112",
         "bestRankPoint":"3979.26",
         "boosts":"358",
         "dBNOs":"212",
         "dailyKills":"11",
         "dailyWins":"0",
         "damageDealt":"37786.28",
         "days":"19",
         "headshotKills":"58",
         "heals":"772",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"257",
         "longestKill":"310.606",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"1863.17",
         "losses":"157",
         "maxKillStreaks":"4",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"1863.17",
         "rankPoints":"3979.26",
         "rankPointsTitle":"4-1",
         "revives":"71",
         "rideDistance":"285183",
         "roadKills":"71",
         "roundMostKills":"11",
         "roundsPlayed":"165",
         "suicides":"3",
         "swimDistance":"188.83",
         "teamKills":"3",
         "timeSurvived":"148833",
         "top10s":"84",
         "vehicleDestroys":"12",
         "walkDistance":"225772",
         "weaponsAcquired":"789",
         "weeklyKills":"11",
         "weeklyWins":"0",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"12",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      },
      {
         "idRank":"35",
         "nombre":"Miguelkill",
         "assists":"2",
         "bestRankPoint":"2175.94",
         "boosts":"11",
         "dBNOs":"4",
         "dailyKills":"0",
         "dailyWins":"0",
         "damageDealt":"430.34308",
         "days":"2",
         "headshotKills":"2",
         "heals":"17",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"5",
         "longestKill":"122.434",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"1671.86",
         "losses":"9",
         "maxKillStreaks":"1",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"1671.86",
         "rankPoints":"2175.94",
         "rankPointsTitle":"3-5",
         "revives":"3",
         "rideDistance":"13977.8",
         "roadKills":"3",
         "roundMostKills":"2",
         "roundsPlayed":"9",
         "suicides":"0",
         "swimDistance":"0",
         "teamKills":"0",
         "timeSurvived":"6902.03",
         "top10s":"2",
         "vehicleDestroys":"0",
         "walkDistance":"9062.15",
         "weaponsAcquired":"49",
         "weeklyKills":"5",
         "weeklyWins":"0",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"0",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      },
      {
         "idRank":"36",
         "nombre":"nokAspen-Gar",
         "assists":"13",
         "bestRankPoint":"2900.57",
         "boosts":"59",
         "dBNOs":"44",
         "dailyKills":"37",
         "dailyWins":"1",
         "damageDealt":"7979.8794",
         "days":"2",
         "headshotKills":"12",
         "heals":"78",
         "killPoints":"0",
         "kills":"50",
         "longestKill":"239.34",
         "longestTimeSurvived":"1741.29",
         "losses":"26",
         "maxKillStreaks":"2",
         "mostSurvivalTime":"1741.29",
         "rankPoints":"2900.57",
         "rankPointsTitle":"3-1",
         "revives":"9",
         "rideDistance":"32589.7",
         "roadKills":"9",
         "roundMostKills":"6",
         "roundsPlayed":"27",
         "suicides":"1",
         "swimDistance":"489.825",
         "teamKills":"1",
         "timeSurvived":"21397.5",
         "top10s":"14",
         "vehicleDestroys":"2",
         "walkDistance":"36975.5",
         "weaponsAcquired":"137",
         "weeklyKills":"50",
         "weeklyWins":"1",
         "winPoints":"0",
         "wins":"1",
         "seasonid":"division.bro.official.pc-2018-04"
      }
   ]
}
```